# Node Red get instance port

Tags: port, node-red

i have a server that starts 10 instance of node-red on different port . with a php page i redirect my users on their port. I need that every node- red instance can get its port but there isn't a node that get localhost:1889 for example (i need 1889).
i'm searching on google from 2 days but nothing

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to set the port on each instance using an environment variable and attaching that to the Node-RED instance using the global variables section of `settings.js`.

That makes the port available to logic within your flows.

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    instancePort: process.env.PORT
},
```

In Node-RED you can then access that variable via a change node or in a function node.